# Run function after jquery slide is done

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, slide

I have a jquery slide function and I´d like to run another function after this one is done.

```
<script>
$('.button').click(function () {
$('#iframehide').toggle('slide');
});
</script>
```

Next funcion I´d like to run, after the above slide is done:

```
$(".zelena-row").mThumbnailScroller("scrollTo", "left");
```

EDIT:
To explain: I made a menu and each "li" is calling different iframe but I am so bad at js that it´s causing me problems and than the code you gave me is not working...

Here is the whole code:

```
<li><div id="iframehide"><iframe width="800" height="1000" frameBorder="0" name="iframe"></iframe></div></li>

<script>
$('.button').click(function () {
$('#iframehide').toggle('slide', function() {
    $(".zelena-row").mThumbnailScroller("scrollTo", "left");
});
});
</script>

<script>
$(".button").on("click", function() {
$(this).toggleClass("underline");
$(".button").not(this).removeClass("underline")
}); 
</script>


<script>
$("#search").on("click", function() {
$('[name="iframe"]')[0].src = "search_iframe.html"; 
});

$("#vstupne").on("click", function() {
$('[name="iframe"]')[0].src = "vstupne_iframe.html";    
});

$("#login").on("click", function() {
$('[name="iframe"]')[0].src = "login_iframe.html";
});

$("#newsletter").on("click", function() {
$('[name="iframe"]')[0].src = "newsletter_iframe.html";
});

$("#kalendar").on("click", function() {
$('[name="iframe"]')[0].src = "kalendar_iframe.html";
});

$("#eshop").on("click", function() {
$('[name="iframe"]')[0].src = "eshop_iframe.html";
});

$("#umelci").on("click", function() {
$('[name="iframe"]')[0].src = "umelci_iframe.html";
});

$("#video").on("click", function() {
$('[name="iframe"]')[0].src = "video_iframe.html";
});

$("#knihovna").on("click", function() {
$('[name="iframe"]')[0].src = "knihovna_iframe.html";
});

$("#kavarna").on("click", function() {
$('[name="iframe"]')[0].src = "kavarna_iframe.html";
});

$("#kontakt").on("click", function() {
$('[name="iframe"]')[0].src = "kontakt_iframe.html";
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

[toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) has a callback parameter that runs after it is complete. You would want to use it like this:

```
$('.button').click(function () {
    $('#iframehide').toggle('slide', function() {
        $(".zelena-row").mThumbnailScroller("scrollTo", "left");
    });
});
```

Comment: Not working, as I mentioned in my edit... Dont know how to fix it.

Comment: @user2295265, what is happening? Are you getting any errors in your javascript console?

Comment: When you scroll to the right and then you clik on one of the menu buttons the right side of wesite (these boxes) fall apart... I dont know why, I am building the website offline, so only way is to post my files: http://uloz.to/xs23JdVd/mg-web-prezentace-zip (open mg_web.html)